# How to read multiple files with error checking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I have a function that reads multiple files. Like this:

```
try:
    a = open("1.txt", "r")
    b = open("2.txt", "r")
    c = open("3.txt", "r")
except IOError:
    print("File {:s} failed".format(a, b or c))
```

I want that I can see which file failed during reading it. Can I somehow specify the IOError for specified file? I mean that if IOError appears in file a, do "command1", if in file b, do "command2" and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IOError` exception is an alias of the [`OSError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError), which has a `filename` attribute. You can use that to switch behaviour based on the file that failed:

```
try:
    a = open("1.txt", "r")
    b = open("2.txt", "r")
    c = open("3.txt", "r")
except OSError as error:
    print("File {:s} failed".format(error.filename))
```

I used the name `OSError`; `IOError` is deprecated and only kept around for backwards compatibility, see [PEP 3151](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/).

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...     open('Nonesuch.txt')
... except OSError as error:
...     print('File {:s} failed'.format(error.filename))
... 
File Nonesuch.txt failed
```

Note that it is the `open()` call that throws the exception, so no assignment has taken place. And because a file object can be referenced from multiple places, including from a list, there is no way to map a file object or filename back to the name you were going to assign it to. If you wanted to know which of `a`, `b` or `c` the file object would have been bound to, you'd have to create your own mapping:

```
filenames = {'1.txt': 'a', '2.txt': 'b', '3.txt': 'c'}
print("File {} failed".format(filenames[error.filename]))
```

Comment: But how can I print, which was the file (a, b or c) that caused the error?

Comment: @Masza: No, because when the `open()` call fails and throws an exception, the assignment isn't executed. If you need to map filenames to variable names by some other means, like a dictionary or `if` statements.

Comment: But does the `filename` tell the name of the file that failed, for example `1.txt` if it fails?

Comment: @Masza: Yes, that's what `filename` contains; `1.txt`, or `2.txt`, or `3.txt`, etc.

Comment: @Masza: you can indeed. The `filename` attribute matches exactly what you passed to `open()`.